# The most simple argument in an axiomatic system

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, hilbert-calculus

I need to find the most simple argument to show that $\vdash_\mathcal{N}((a\rightarrow ((b\rightarrow c)\rightarrow (\lnot d\rightarrow c)))\rightarrow a)\rightarrow a$, where $\mathcal{N}$ has the following axiom schema and modus ponens:

1. $\Gamma\vdash_{\mathcal{N}} \beta$, if $\beta\in\Gamma$
2. $\Gamma\vdash_{\mathcal{N}}\alpha \rightarrow \big(\beta \rightarrow\alpha \big)$
3. $\Gamma\vdash_{\mathcal{N}}\big({\alpha \rightarrow \big(\beta \rightarrow\gamma \big)}\big) \rightarrow  \big({\big(\alpha \rightarrow\beta \big) \rightarrow \big(\alpha \rightarrow\gamma \big)} \big)$
4. $\Gamma\vdash_{\mathcal{N}}\big( \lnot \beta \rightarrow \lnot \alpha \big) \rightarrow \big(\alpha \rightarrow \beta \big)$

$\Gamma\vdash_{\mathcal{N}} B$, if $B\in\Gamma$. I know I could do this by constructing a truth table, but that's not very "simple". I've also tried to simplify the formula, but that didn't seem to work. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: How would a truth-table help you with this??

Comment: @Bram28 By ending up with a column consisting of just T, we may conclude that the formula is valid and by completeness of $\mathcal{N}$ , it is also derivable in $\mathcal{N}$.

Comment: So you don't have to provide an actual derivation? And you can assume N is complete? Ok, yes, then you're right, showing it to be valid would do the job. And it's easily shown to be valid: if $a$ is true, then the consequent of the whole conditional is true, so the whole statement is true. If $a$ is false, then $a \rightarrow lotsofstuff$ is true, hence $(a \rightarrow lotsofstuff) \rightarrow a$ is false, and hence the whole statement true.

Comment: @IsomorphicTwin -  Are you allowed to use the [deduction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem)?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco Yes, you are.

Comment: What is your metric for "simple"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use exploit the fact that $\mathcal{N}$ is complete, then indeed all you need to do is to show that the statement is valid. This can easily be done by a proof by contradiction that shows that any statement of the form $((\phi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow \psi$ is valid:

Suppose $((\phi\rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow \psi)\rightarrow \psi$ is false. Then $(\phi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow \phi$ is true, but $\phi$ is false. But with $\phi$ being false, $\phi \rightarrow \psi$ is true, and hence $(\phi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow \phi$ is false and hence we have reached a contradiction. Hence, it is impossible for $((\phi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow \phi) \rightarrow \phi$ to be false, and hence it is valid.